# Batch file for 1 mouse click

Tags: file, batch-file, timer, click

Hello just wondering is their any possibility for a batch file to have a user entry specified time? Lets say for example i want to enter a time of 26 minutes, after that the batch file will be like a countdown timer when it reaches 0 it does 1 mouse click to an icon on the desktop? or where to pointer of the mouse was pointed?

Comment: Batch file isn't designed for that purpose. It can't execute a command based on events such as mouse click, mouse move, window maximize, etc. Use *AutoIt* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or AutoIT, it's very easy to do these thing with this... or you could just get an autoclicker...

Example

```
#Persistent
Pause
SetTimer, MouseClicklabel , 1560000 ; 1000 = 1 second, meaning 1560000 = 26 Minutes
Pause::Pause
MouseClicklabel:
Click
Return
```

The toggle key is Pause